# High resolution Timers on ARM running on less than 300Mhz clock

Tags: linux, architecture, asynchronous, arm

I think HRT with nanosec resolution very well work with high speed processors (1GHz or more) but how if the system clock is less than 300Mhz? Can i get the nanosec resolution. I want to invoke a function after starting timer for 10ns. If yes, how can I verify?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this is likely specific to the core or chip vendor.  if it a timer in the core then look at the trm for that core, what divisors are available, when you can interrupt, etc.  Clearly if the reference clock to the timer is 300Mhz then you get what 3 1/3 ns at best?  you would need a timer driven off of a faster clock which probably is a vendor specific thing can you run the timers faster than the arm core?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve a 10 ns start timer delay even with 1+ GHz processors, as there is some latency involved in processing interrupts, and that by itself is usually more than 10 ns, not to mention the function call itself or the instructions executed by it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, I do agree. Unfortunately I dont have the provision to use GPIO timers provided by the system, I have to use Linux system calls like timer_create and timer_settime. WIth a 300Mhz system, what best resolution I can achieve? How can I verify?

Comment: It is probably bettter when you describe *why* you need the timing to be that strict. What do you want to achieve?